# Getting invalid operand to binary expression ('id' and 'id') and wrong calculation value

Tags: ios, objective-c

Getting this error "invalid operand to binary expression ('id' and 'id')" when I try to do some basic math with values stored in an array. The commented out code works, but gives the wrong value for some reason.

```
@implementation OMOGradesViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    // Call init method implemented by the superclass
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if(self){
        // Create array of grades
        self.grades = @[@80, @70, @60, @50, @40];
        // self.grades = @[@"80", @"70", @"60", @"50", @"40"];

}

    // Return the address to the new object
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)calculateAvg:(id)sender
{

    for(NSArray *a in self.grades)
        NSLog(@"%@", a);

    int *avg = ([self.grades objectAtIndex:0] + [self.grades objectAtIndex:1]);

    /*int avg = ((int)self.grades[0] + (int)self.grades[1] + (int)self.grades[2]
    + (int)self.grades[3] + (int)self.grades[4])/5;

    NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",avg];

    self.averageLabel.text = strFromInt;
    NSLog(@"%@", strFromInt);*/


}

@end
```

Comment: On which line is the warning showing up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So many things are wrong here. This:

```
int *avg = ([self.grades objectAtIndex:0] + [self.grades objectAtIndex:1]);
```

should be:

```
int avg = [self.grades[0] intValue] + [self.grades[1] intValue];
```

You can't add `NSNumber` objects directly. You need to get their `int` values (using `intValue`).

And your `avg` can't be an `int` pointer, just a plain old `int`.

I also replaced the call to `objectAtIndex:` with the modern array access syntax.